# Date time range search ASP.NET MVC

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc

In my ASP.NET MVC application, datetime is stored as `2022-03-02 10:47:45.000` and if I want to search data within the date range the selected date shows as `2022-03-02` and when I run it, it wont return the data.

How to query to get data removing the time from every record on the database table?

This is my code:

```
var report = (from prodMovmnt in db.ProductionMovements 
              join productMain in db.Products on prodMovmnt.ProductId equals productMain.Id 
              join sizeMain in db.ProductSizes on prodMovmnt.ProductSizeId equals sizeMain.Id 
              where prodMovmnt.Status == true 
                    && prodMovmnt.Movement == "OUT" 
                    && prodMovmnt.Out_Date > FromDate 
                    && prodMovmnt.Out_Date < Todate 
              select new SelledItems 
                         {
                             ProductName = productMain.Name,
                             ProductSize = sizeMain.Size,
                         }).ToList();
```

Comment: **SoldItems** - not "SelledItems" - that's not a word in English .....

Comment: datetime is not stored as `2022-03-02 10:47:45.000`.  A date has no format until it is displayed for a specific localization. And to remove time just to `FromDate.Date`

Comment: You only posted a LINQ query, probably to Entity Framework. It's unclear what the property and parameter types are. Is `Out_Date` a `DateTime` or string? Are `FromDate` and `ToDate` dates or strings? This query would work if `DateTime` was used. With strings - don't use strings. There's no guarantee the strings would have the same format, or that the format would be sortable. So don't use strings

Comment: BTW Entity Framework is an ORM, not a database driver. It deals with entities and relations not tables. You shouldn't have to join entities in code, EF itself would generate the joins based on the relations between entities. `db.Products.Where(p=>p.ProductMovement.Status==true).Select(p=>new SelectedItem{ ProductName=p.Name,ProductSize=p.ProductSize.Size)` would work fine

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos ``Out_Date`` column is ``DateTime`` and in the controller ``FromDate and ``Todate`` are also the ``DateTime``. But I want that If I select ``Date`` now, It pass the ``DateTime Now``, which does not shows the same date earlier saved records. So what I want is I want to get only the data with regarding the  ``Date`` from the ``Out_Date`` not considering the ``Time``.

Comment: Use `DateTime.Today` if you want just the date and `DateTime.Date` to strip the time part, eg `Out_Date >= FromDate.Date && Out_Date <= ToDate.Date`